# How can i get the raw SQL of changes in models.py including table creation

Tags: django, django-models

**I want to get the SQL query of the changes i have made in my application model**
Like if i have written in models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20,)
  dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

so i should get a raw SQL for the same like

```
Create table employee(
name varchar(50),
dob datetime
)
```